# How set increment of value in Laravel (OctoberCMS) query?

Tags: laravel, increment, octobercms

OctoberCMS (472), Laravel: I would like to the "visitors" [integer] increment by one after every reload.

```
function onStart(){
        ModelName::where('slug', '=', $this->param('slug'))->increment('visitors');
    }
```

After that I reload the page, visitors increment by two, not with one. Why? I can't understand.

When I try increment('visitors', 2) - incremented by four. How and why?

Comment: Did you log how many times onStart is called ?

LifeCycle
...
Layout `onStart()` function, 
Page `onStart()` function
.....

Comment: can you please share where you are writing your code , its page , layout or anything else